# Camel split xml keeping some nodes

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, splitter

I have:

```
<Message>
    <Header>
    .....some more nodes.....
    </Header>

    <Element>
   .....some more nodes.....
    </Element>

    <Element>
   .....some more nodes.....
    </Element>
   .....more Element nodes......
</Message>
```

I want to split by nodes Element, but keep the rest of the message (Header) included in every message. For example using this xml I want to get 2 other, which looks like:

```
<Message>  <!--root node is alive -->
    <Header> <!--header included in every message -->
    .....some more nodes.....
    </Header>

    <Element> <!--only one -->
   .....some more nodes.....
    </Element>
</Message>
```

Using splitter I can get only:

```
    <Element>
   .....some more nodes.....
    </Element>
```

I was trying to use jaxb marshaler to iterate over Element nodes, but the idea failed due to :unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Also, I was trying to use

```
.split(xpath("//Element"), new MyAgreggatorStrategy())
```

hoping I could process message with myself, but I got null in oldMessage received everytime.

Can you share your ideas.

What if I store "in" message as some propery, then make split and then passing through custom processor will construct everything I need? I hope, there is some better sollution with camel.
Thanks

Update. Right now I've implemented this functionality, the way I asked earlier. (Store header as property, make splitting, restore message: like concatenation " + header + transformedBody +

but I have to wrap with my additional processors (before split and after) all my routes. Stil think my problem should be something typical and general, Think I missed something.

Update2. 
Replaced 2 processors with 1 splitter bean

```
public String[] splitBody(Exchange exchange) {
    String header = XPathBuilder.xpath("//Header").evaluate(exchange, String.class);
    String element = XPathBuilder.xpath("//Element").evaluate(exchange, String.class);

    String[] arr = element.split("</Element>");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = "<Message>" + header + arr[i] + "</Message>";
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I've wanted to do exactly this in the past but could not find any ready made component after a lot of searching. Since I was dealing with large messages I ended up writing a custom component using stax which was general enough to handle any type of message. I think a custom solution is the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, fortunately out-of-the box splitter is not enough configurable right now

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to transform your xml using xslt which can then use the camel split with tokenizeXML like  .to("xslt:").split().tokenizeXML("Message")

XSL for your case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Messages>
            <xsl:call-template name="Message" />
        </Messages>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Message" match="/Message">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Message/Element">
            <Message>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/Message/Header"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
            </Message>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add property  to the exchange that will link to your headers Map. This property will be available inside splitter.
Something like this:

```
        <setProperty propertyName="parentHeaders">
            <simple>${headers}</simple>
        </setProperty>
```

and inside splitter you can refer to the headers by key "parentHeaders".

Hope this will help you

Comment: I'll try, this can simplify things a little. Thanks!